# Spoofing domains in Facebook

Tags: malware, spoofing

Over this past week my Facebook's timeline have been flooded by people posting "teenagers sex videos" and tagging a lot of people.

It's common in Facebook to see this kind of malware spreading to people that believe and click on everything, but what I see different this time is that the domain of the "video" is `apple.com`.

How is it possible?

For example:
[image]

Comment: You can make the link anything you like - not sure what your question means

Comment: Are you sure that's not the subtitle of the post rather than the website?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website? This will make it rather obvious on how they do it and google found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is "how such a spoofing possible"? It's not a question how a domain owner protects it, because you can't control the whole web. The spoof IS a kind of lie, so EVERYTHING is possible here. The purpose *is* to shock you, so if you will see a BBC or CNN domains under this XXX videos - feel no surprise.

Comment: Yes that's the question. I'm not asking at any point how can someone protect the domain for preventing the spoofing, I'm asking how is it possible to do this spoofing in Facebook

Comment: @yzT Facebook does not check the link ownership, actually. It parses a lin target's microformats, if there's one, and constructs a widget for it. It just copies and pastes - it can not afford to make a check, it will make too heavy load on a system. And that was abused : I think a microformat reply was poisoned with apple.com domain, and it was just copy-pasted